# Performing pooja to God and Goddess on the same day

Tags: rituals, worship

While performing poojas to gods and goddesses on the same day for example - Satyanarayana Pooja and Vaibhava Lakshmi Pooja - which one is to be performed first?

Comment: You should do one vratam at a time.